# Appending value to a column based on condition

Tags: awk, sed

I have a csv file `file.csv`.

```
Action,Type,Name,Destination
Add,File,File1.war,path
Add,File,File2.properties,path
Add,Directory,File3.war,path
```

I have given this file as a input to a while loop and it checks for each and every row the presence of file in source location and destination location, and if the conditions are true then i need to return value to a new column named remarks and add the remarks saying whether it is success or fail.

```
while IFS="," read f1 f2 f3 f4
do
statements
done < file.csv.
```

I want to append a value in the 5th column based on the output of each row.
The output I need is somewhat similar to this

```
Action,Type,Name,Destination,Remarks
Add,File,File1.war,path,Success
Add,File,File2.properties,path,Fail
Add,Directory,File3.war,path,Fail
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: We can't help you do something if you don't explain what you actually need to do. Please [edit] your question and tell us what condition needs to be met. How can we know whether each line should have `True` or `False`? Also, as a general rule, using the shell for this sort of thing is a very bad idea: it is hard to do safely, the syntax is awful, and it is very, very slow.

Comment: I'm checking the existence of the file in source and destination location. If the files are present in both the location i need to return a value to the csv(Last column).
So that it becomes easy for documentation, do we have any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Some solution in `awk` based on the few information you gave us with some nonsense check (`NR % 2` → even line number) to be replaced by you:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} {print $0,(NR % 2 ? "True": "False")}' << 'EOF'
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
EOF
```

Use `$1`,`$2` etc. inside the `awk` script to refer to the columns and base your checks on:

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,True
1,2,3,4,False
1,2,3,4,True
1,2,3,4,False
```

No support for escaped commas (e.g. `\,` or using quotes).